# How to make a custom CSS border with border-image?

Tags: css, border, border-image

I am trying but failing miserably on trying to make a custom css border like this using the border-image shorthand property.Is there a way to do partial borders? Maybe there is a better way to achieve what I am trying to do? I could always just insert this image but it doesn't seem like this would resize well once you do that.

[image: CSS Header Image]

Comment: Can you share your codes (HTML, CSS)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also achieve this by directly positioning the `content` inside the `container` as below.

Here we have positioned the `content` using margin, we can also do this by absolutely positioning the content.

```css
.container {
  border: 5px solid #000;
  border-bottom: 0;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.content {
  background: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 5px solid #000;
  border-right: 5px solid #000;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: -15px auto 0; /* height 25px + 5px border = 30/2 = 15 */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">Header</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a responsive solution with less of code and with transparency:

```css
.container {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  border:5px solid;
  border-image:linear-gradient(to bottom,transparent 10px,#000 10px,#000 100%) 4;
  height:50px;
  margin:5px;
}

.top {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.top::before,
.top::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 8px);
  width: 100vw;
  height: 15px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #000 content-box;
}

.top::before {
  right: 100%;
  border-right: 5px solid;
}

.top::after {
  left: 100%;
  border-left: 5px solid;
}

body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="top">Hello</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="top">More Hello</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="top">H</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex` to wrap and "play" with `border` to div inside `wrap`

```css
.wrap{
display:flex;
width:100%;
}
.wrap div{
width:calc(100vw / 3);
}
.header{
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 5px solid black;
    border-left: 5px solid black;
}
.border{
margin-top: 5px;
height:8px;
border-top: 5px solid black;
}
.b-left{
border-left: 5px solid black;
}
.b-right{
border-right: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
      <div class="border b-left"></div>
      <div class="header">Header</div>
      <div class="border b-right"></div>
</div>
```